# Sync a git repository between work and home pc

Tags: git

My source code are managed by git.  I work at office on day time and at home on night time.  How may I sync the repository from work and home?

The solution so far I google around able to pull or push the commit changes only.  What if I want sync  untracked and staging files/folders too?

Answer (score 3):

Syncing untracked files with git is not possible. But you could put your repository into Dropbox (www.dropbox.com) and let dropbox sync all files while using git for code revision management.

Comment: +1 I do this with some of my code just between multiple machines in my house. Dropbox works very well.

Comment: I am thinking to create a WIP branch just to sync between home and work pc.  I will commit those untracked and modified files into WIP branch first.  If I finish my work, I merge the WIP branch into master.

Answer (score 1):

A work-in-progress branch would definitely be my choice as the best way to handle this. Using a USB drive or Dropbox folder as a substitute for a version control system which is perfectly capable of doing what you want seems like a backwards step.

Answer (score 0):

How about, have a USB flash. Use two batch files, like this:

FROM_PC_TO_USB.bat

```
@echo off
robocopy /E /Purge /copy:DAT /MT:16 /MIR C:\My\Repo\Path \My_Usb_Path
```

FROM_USB_TO_PC.bat

```
@echo off
robocopy /E /Purge /copy:DAT /MT:16 /MIR \My_Usb_Path C:\My\Repo\Path
```

Robocopy is an insanely fast and efficient file/folder sync application that's been hiding quietly in windows for a few versions.